# Lagrange multipliers question with 2 constraints

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n|\sum x_i=n/3, \sum x_i^2=n \}$

$f(x)=\sum x_i^3$

> Prove that max of f on A is of the form: $x=(a,a,.....,a,b,b...,b)$
>   (no need to find a or b).

So with Lagrange multiplier method I used these as my constraints:

$g(x)=\sum x_i-n/3=0$

$h(x)=\sum x_i^2-n=0$

so $f_{x_i}=\lambda g_{x_i}+ \mu h_{x_i}$

we get n equations of:

$3x_i^2=\lambda+\mu2x_i$

summing them all up I deduced that $ \lambda=3-\frac{2n\mu}{3}$

however I can't find lambda and prove what's needed..

Any help?

Comment: what about resubstituting into the equations $$ 3x_i^2 = \lambda + \mu 2 x_i$$

Comment: you're right I think i got it, now I deduced that $\mu=0$ and then its easy to see that for each i $x_i^2=1$ and then the solution is clear